# SQL Syntax Error with Jruby under EngineYard

Tags: sqlite, jruby

I am having some fun with Jruby, but I am having troubles getting my app deployed on EngineYard. Under deploy I am getting the follow error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2147483647) DEFAULT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `iterations` CHANGE `points` `points` longtext(2147483647) DEFAULT NULL
```

Even though my database.yml uses SQLITE and not MySQL. The migration file is listed as:

```
class ChangePointsToLongtext < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :iterations, :points, :longtext
  end

  def down
    change_column :iterations, :points, :text
  end
end
```

I am almost certrain its the `change_column` - I have tried `t.change` and looked around for other syntax changes. I think it may be an issue with the Jruby version running on EngineYard - which I can't update.

My GemFile looks like this:

```
platforms :jruby do
 gem 'jruby-openssl'
 gem 'trinidad'
 gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
gem 'jdbc-mysql', :require => false
 gem 'jdbc-sqlite3', :require => false
 end
```

So I believe I have all the relevant gems loaded in order to establish a database under Jruby, although I may be very wrong! I think I just need an alternative to `change_column`

Has anyone run into a similar problem? Or have any advice on changes? any help is always much appreciated!

Thanks
C

Answer (score 0):

First, please use https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/ if you need help with Engine Yard.

Second, EY does not support SQLite. When your application is deployed to EY, EY will replace `database.yml` with appropriate information so that your application can use DB indicated in the environment configuration. The DB choice should default to MySQL when you set up your environment.

And finally, it appears that something is generating the incorrect SQL statement. Seeing that a similar migration works with MRI and `mysql2` adapter, the issue probably lies with JDBC adapter. You can open an issue at https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues or http://bugs.jruby.org.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I did try engineyard, they just never got back to me.

Comment: If you can tell me the ticket number, I'll look into it. Sorry for your bad experience.